# Is is possible to replace SUB QUERIES with WITH CLAUSE?

Tags: sql, subquery, with-statement

Is is possible to replace SUB QUERIES with WITH CLAUSE ?

Comment: Yes . Can you be more specific with your question.

Comment: With clauses are basically named sub queries, it's hard to understand what you mean by 'replace'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace non-correlated subqueries with common table expressions (CTEs).

This applies to most subqueries in the `from` clause.  It also applies to uncorrelated queries in other clauses.

Comment: **non-correlated** being the keyword.